# questions about EntityFramework.Extended caching

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, entityframework.extended

1. When I use `FromCache` or `FromeCacheFirstOrDefault`, what is the behavior when the item is not in the cache? Do I need to run a separate query to load the data from the real DB, or do those methods fall back to querying the DB for me?
2. Does the cache persist across multiple instances of my `DbContext`? Or is there a separate cache for each instance of `DbContext`?
3. When I get an object from the cache to use as a foreign key, do I need to attach it to the `DbContext` or should it be already attached? Or does it matter?
4. How does it work with the Local collection? If I call `Add` on `DbSet`, can I then get that object from the Cache before calling `SaveChanges()`?

I originally posted these questions on GitHub but didn't get any traction: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/111

Comment: Did you ever find any answers to these questions? I'm looking at using this as well...